# Testing an Angular Promise with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

The following test keeps failing and I can't figure out why? I am trying to figure out how to test defereds/promises with Jasmine.

**Error**

```
Expected undefined to be 'Resolved Data'.
```

**Test**

```
    describe('Queued Repository', function () {
    var ctrl,
        rootScope,
        scope,
        service;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('testApp');

        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, TestSrvc) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            service = TestSrvc;
        });
    });

    afterEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }));

    it('test something', function () {
        expect(service.calculate(1, 5)).toBe(6);
    });

    it('resolves promises', function () {
        var result;

        service.getPromise().then(function (data) {
            result = data;
        });

        rootScope.$apply();
        expect(result).toBe('Resolved Data');
    });
});
```

**Service**

```
    var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.service('TestSrvc', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http', function ($q, $timeout, $http) {
    return {
        getPromise: function () {
            var d = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function () {
                d.resolve('Defered Result');
            }, 5000);

            return d.promise;
        },
        getSomething: function () {
            return "Test";
        },
        calculate: function (x, y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `expect(result).toEqual('Defered Result');`?

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo - Yes, but it still does not work.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean, result is `undefined`.  If it was a promise returned `$http` I would suggest calling `$httpBackend.flush()` before making your assertion. However using the `$q` service is another story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling `$timeout.flush()` before `expect(result).toBe('Resolved Data');`.

Comment: Thanks a TON! Do I still need the $rootScope.$apply()?

Comment: I get "unexpected request" GET http://my.test.service/someObject/someId no request expected

Comment: You're not showing the full content of file that you want test, from where this GET calls come? Why `$http` is injected to the service?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you will need to call both `$timeout.flush()` AND `$rootScope.$apply()`.

Explanation: `$timeout.flush()` will force your `$timeout` in the service to run immediately. Your service will then call '`resolve`' - but the `promise.then()` will not be called until the subsequent digest cycle; therefore you will need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` to propagate any 'resolves' and 'watches' - which will occur synchronously.

`NOTE:` In Jasmine, ensure that your `promise.then()` function appears `BEFORE` your call to `$rootScope.$apply` otherwise it will not fire the `promise.then()` function. (I haven't figured out why this is the case in Jasmine.)